# Code sign Java app for OS X Gatekeeper

Tags: java, macos, code-signing, osx-gatekeeper, app-bundle

I am trying to distribute a Java application to OS X users. I am not using the Mac store - it is to be distributed through my own website. Whatever I try, OS X's Gatekeeper rejects the app.

Here's my method:

(1) Build the app as usual, get a JAR file

(2) Use `appbundler` as described here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/packagingAppsForMac.html. This creates a .app around my JAR which runs nicely, and contains the JVM in the `MyApp.app/Contents/PlugIns` directory.

(3) Sign the app with my Developer certificate:

`codesign -s 'Developer ID Application: MyCompany Ltd' --deep MyApp.app`

...process completes successfully

(4) Verify that the .app will adhere to Gatekeeper's iron-fist laws:

`spctl --assess --verbose=4 --type execute MyApp.app`

...and the result I get back is:

```
MyApp.app: a sealed resource is missing or invalid
```

Doesn't seem very verbose to me! What could I be doing wrong? Or how can I get more information?

SO/Google searches around 'a sealed resource...' refer to signing frameworks (which I don't have) or suggest signing with the `--force` option (which I tried but doesn't work).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't use `--deep`.  It sounds like the right option to use, since you also need to sign the embedded JRE, but it won't work.  From [Apple's docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2206/_index.html):

> Important: While the --deep option can be applied to a signing
>   operation, this is not recommended. We recommend that you sign code
>   inside out in individual stages (as Xcode does automatically). Signing
>   with --deep is for emergency repairs and temporary adjustments only.

After a lot of hair-pulling, I cobbled this together from various tutorials.  [This one](http://speling.shemnon.com/blog/2014/04/10/getting-your-java-app-in-the-mac-app-store/) was the most helpful.  Here was my final solution as an Ant script:

```
<!-- code sign -->
<exec executable="chmod">
    <arg line="a+w ${build.dir}/Mac/MyApp.app/Contents/PlugIns/jre"/>
</exec>

<apply executable="codesign"> <!-- note: this loops through the contents of dir -->
    <arg line="-f -s 'Developer ID Application: My Organization'"/>
    <fileset dir="${build.dir}/Mac/MyApp.app/Contents/PlugIns/jre" />
</apply>

<exec executable="codesign" dir="${build.dir}/Mac"> 
    <arg line="-f -s 'Developer ID Application: My Organization' MyApp.app/Contents/PlugIns/jre"/>
</exec>

<exec executable="codesign" dir="${build.dir}/Mac"> 
    <arg line="-f -s 'Developer ID Application: My Organization' MyApp.app/Contents/PlugIns/jre/Contents/_CodeSignature/CodeResources"/>
</exec>

<!-- also codesign anything else in _CodeSignature (see comments) -->

<exec executable="codesign" dir="${build.dir}/Mac">
    <arg line="-f -s 'Developer ID Application: My Organization' MyApp.app"/>
</exec>


<!-- verify codesign -->
<exec executable="codesign" dir="${build.dir}/Mac" failonerror="true">
    <arg line="-vv MyApp.app"/>
</exec>


<!-- verify gatekeeper -->
<exec executable="spctl" dir="${build.dir}/Mac" failonerror="true">
    <arg line="-vv --assess --type execute MyApp.app"/>
</exec>
```

Another thing to look out for is not to use the command-line `zip` to package your app after signing, because it will break the codesign of the app.  You should package it using `productbuild`, PackageMaker, `xip`, or in a dmg.

Comment: Many thanks for the response, really appreciated. Unfortunately this get  as far as the verification (`codesign -vv MyApp.app` line) then dies with `[exec] MyApp.app: code object is not signed at all` / `[exec] In subcomponent: MyApp.app/Contents/PlugIns/jre/Contents/_CodeSignature/CodeDirectory`. Any ideas?

Comment: @HughHughTeotl I don't get a `_CodeSignature/CodeDirectory` when I run it -- not sure what is causing the difference.  You'll have to sign everything in `_CodeSignature`, so just add `_CodeSignature/CodeDirectory` to the list (and anything else in there).  Also, be sure you are signing in OS X 10.9 or later.  If you use an older version of OS X, the code signing will not work.

Comment: AWESOME! That seems to work. I will edit your answer with that small change so I can accept it (hope that's OK). Many many thanks.

Comment: @HughHughTeotl Looks like the edit was rejected (not by me).  I added a note about it to the answer.  Thanks!