# How to distribute Java application 7.0 and above on Mac 10 and above?

Tags: java, xcode, macos, jar

I need to run my Java application on Mac. I could find this [tutorial](http://alvinalexander.com/apple/mac/java-jar-bundler/Getting_started_with_Jar_Bu.shtml) to use Xcode to bundle the application. The tutorial asks readers to have access to Jar Bundle application butI could not find it in the /Developer/Applications/Java Tools/ folder.

After that I came across this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15375490/why-is-jar-bundler-gone-in-mac-os-x-mountain-lion-10-8-2) which seems is offering a good method to do it.

However, I am wondering if there is any better way to get the job done rather than the one mentioned there.

Comment: Take a look at [Packaging a Java App for Distribution on a Mac](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/packagingAppsForMac.html), [Java Application Bundler](https://java.net/projects/appbundler) and [Take your Java application to the Mac App Store](http://www.intransitione.com/blog/take-java-to-app-store/) for more details

Comment: This [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24978212/jar-to-mac-osx-app-bundle-with-app-bundler/24992828#24992828) might also help

Comment: Another useful resource is https://bitbucket.org/infinitekind/appbundler — it contains an Ant task that creates the app bundle for you. What it does not do though, is signing your app, which is a requirements these days for the store. But here [Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/packagingAppsForMac.html#sign) can help.

Comment: Here's a more thorough example of code signing a Java app: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26938414/code-sign-java-app-for-os-x-gatekeeper/26938545#26938545

Comment: none of these helped.

Comment: As of JDK14 you can also use **`jpackage`** see https://stackoverflow.com/a/66511673/191246

Answer (score 3):

The Mac OS X utilities **Jar Bundler**, **Icon Composer**, and **PacakgeMaker** are all deprecated.  Even the various **AppBundler** projects out there seem destine to fade away.

The way forward looks to be **[javapackager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/javapackager.html)**, which is included in the JDK.

The `-deploy -native pkg` options will convert a Java application (Executable JAR) into a native macOS installer.

Example commands:

```
$ jar cmf MainClass.txt ShowTime.jar *.class
$ javapackager -deploy -native pkg -srcfiles ShowTime.jar \
   -appclass ShowTime -name ShowTime \
   -outdir deploy -outfile ShowTime -v
```

Output: `deploy/bundles/ShowTime-1.0.pkg`

[image: screenshot]

I posted a detailed tutorial at:
 [centerkey.com/mac/java](https://centerkey.com/mac/java/)

For better or worse, **javapackager** bundles the JRE and the resulting `.pkg` file is over 60MB.

Comment: it's possible use javapackager to create an installer to install in addition to java application, some other resources like driver, required by application to work?

Comment: Yes, but I have not tried it.  I believe you want to use the `-srcdir` flag to include the folder containing the desired resources.  The flag sets the "*Base directory of the files to package.*"  Alternatively, you could put the resources in the JAR file before running `javapackager`.

Answer (score 0):

As Dem says, I user `javapackager` like this:

Open terminal and go to working folder like `cd Desktop/`
and type;

```
javapackager \
> -deploy \
> -title AppTitle \
> -name AppName \
> -appclass your.app.class \
> -native dmg \
> -outdir ~/YourOutputDir \
> -outfile out \
> -srcfiles your.jar
```