# Java: Mac App Not Signed With Apple Submission Certificate

Tags: java, macos, app-store, code-signing, osx-gatekeeper

I am trying to upload my java app to the Mac App Store. I have been following the instructions here: [Code sign Java app for OS X Gatekeeper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26938414/code-sign-java-app-for-os-x-gatekeeper). Naturally since I want it on the Mac App store I am signing it with my "3rd Party Mac Developer Application: Certificate." The most recent time I tried to submit it, Apple says that the app is not signed with an Apple Submission Certificate. When I run: 'codesign --verify -vvvv myapp.app' I get this:

> --prepared:PathToMyApp/myapp.app/Contents/PlugIns/jdk1.8.0_31.jdk
>   --validated:PathToMyApp/myapp.app/Contents/PlugIns/jdk1.8.0_31.jdk
>
> myapp.app: valid on disk
>
> myapp.app: satisfies its Designated Requirement

When I run: 'spctl -vvvv --assess --type execute myapp.app' I get:

> myapp.app: rejected
>
> origin=3rd Party Mac Developer Application: me (XXXXXXXXXX)

When I run: 'codesign -dvvv myapp.app' I get:

> Executable=PathToMyApp/myapp.app/Contents/MacOS/myapp
>
> Identifier=myapp
>
> Format=bundle with Mach-O thin (x86_64)
>
> CodeDirectory v=20200 size=270 flags=0x0(none) hashes=5+5 location=embedded
>
> Hash type=sha1 size=20
>   CDHash=2b8e4d61e30c01e5d6ac3f4a3381be2df2efa6b8
>
> Signature size=4347
>
> Authority=3rd Party Mac Developer Application: me (XXXXXXXXXX)
>
> Authority=Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority
>
> Authority=Apple Root CA
>
> Signed Time=Mar 3, 2015, 1:57:39 PM
>
> Info.plist entries=22
>
> TeamIdentifier=XXXXXXXXXX
>
> Sealed Resources **version=2** rules=12 files=7
>
> Internal requirements count=1 size=36

Likewise when I run Apple's check signature program, I get:

> test-requirement: code failed to satisfy specified code requirement(s)
>
> myapp.app: The target is not signed with Developer ID or by the Mac App Store.
>   NO

I know that Apple also checks with:

> codesign --verify -vvvv -R='anchor apple generic and certificate 1[field.1.2.840.113635.100.6.2.1] exists and (certificate leaf[field.1.2.840.113635.100.6.1.2] exists or certificate leaf[field.1.2.840.113635.100.6.1.4] exists)' myapp.app

I get:

> --prepared:PathToMyApp/myapp.app/Contents/PlugIns/jdk1.8.0_31.jdk
>   --validated:PathToMyApp/myapp.app/Contents/PlugIns/jdk1.8.0_31.jdk
>
> myapp.app: valid on disk
>
> myapp.app: satisfies its Designated Requirement
>
> test-requirement: code failed to satisfy specified code requirement(s)

If I sign everything with the 'Developer ID Application:' certificate then Application Loader says that it must be signed with the '3rd Party Mac Developer' certificate and that it isn't signed with a v1 signature. I've been working on this for close to a week with no success.

What am I doing wrong?

-Also if it helps I am bundling the app with Netbeans' built in native packager on Yosemite 10.10.2. I've tried Appbundler, and a few others and haven't gotten much success either.

Comment: The problem might be that you need to submit the app wrapped in an installer, not just the app.  Check out this blog post: http://speling.shemnon.com/blog/2014/04/10/getting-your-java-app-in-the-mac-app-store/

Comment: I package it with productbuild, but when I upload it to Apple, they extract it and run tests on the .app